# Remote Debugging for Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, unix, jetty, remote-debugging, embedded-jetty

I want to remotely debug java code running on embedded Jetty server which is running on Unix environment. Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in the jvm running jetty?

Comment: please share the params I need to set

Comment: Check the duplicate.